# Laravel routing not working 404 not found after deployment

Tags: laravel

I just uploaded my project on shared hosting but the index page is the only working page, and when I try to navigate to any other page I face 404 not found page, I enable the Rewrite in .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews -Indexes
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

# Send Requests To Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# php -- BEGIN cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
# Set the “ea-php80” package as the default “PHP” programming language.
<IfModule mime_module>
  AddHandler application/x-httpd-ea-php80 .php .php8 .phtml
</IfModule>
# php -- END cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
```

but nothing changed, can anyone help me?

Comment: Can you give more details about your dir structure? For example, is your project in public_html folder or any other dir?

Comment: Is the web root pointing to the `public` directory?

Comment: I will never understand why people upload a Laravel project to a shared hosting where you don't have SSH access or full control over it... but as @Rwd mentioned, we are pretty sure your issue is that you are not pointing the `DocumentRoot` to the `public` directory, so you are "literally" accessing `page/public` instead of `public` as your web root.

Comment: you say the index page works ... as in you go to `yoursite.com` and you get the index route? if so then it just sounds like rewriting isn't working

Answer (score 0):

if your server working nginx. it's working with htaccess. than for solving this problem you need to add this code to httpd configuration

> |?DOCROOT=/home/your-duser/domains/your-domin/public_html/| location /
> {
> try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
> }

[image: like this image]